# How to style elements using CSS instead of HTML presentation tags?

Tags: html, css

For example,

```
That is a <em>car</em>. That <strong>car</strong> doesn't start.
```

In this case can we use CSS instead of HTML tags to give design to it?

Comment: <em> and <strong> can we replace it with  css

Comment: What is your question, if you can set ```italic``` and ```bold``` in ```css```?

Comment: You would need at least a `span` to delimit to which text to apply the style.

Comment: Do you want to *replace* those tags with CSS?  Or do you want to *style* those tags with CSS?  I don't see how the former makes much sense.

Comment: [Duplicate](//www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+html+u+and+strong+vs+css) of [`<strong>` vs. `font-weight:bold` & `<em>` vs. `font-style:italic`](/q/4939807/4642212). Please read the documentation on [`<u>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/u), [`<em>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em), and [`<strong>`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strong). Particularly keep an eye on the _semantics_ of each element.

Comment: Related: [Are new HTML5 elements like `<section>` and `<article>` pointless?](/q/3822024/4642212); HTML defines structure _and semantics_. CSS defines only layout and presentation. (There’s also [`role="presentation"`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_presentation_role) in HTML.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you would still need to create something like a span with the proper class. I'm not sure why `<span class="strong">` is better than `<strong>`.

The old `<b>` and `<i>` were kind of clumsy, `<em>` and `<strong>` were improvements. But almost everything in HTML could be boiled down to a single tag with classes and crazy CSS to use the classes to turn the single tag into paragraphs, and tables, and lists, and etc...but would that really be better for anybody than what we have now?

Answer (score 0):

You could, even though not recommended, use span tags with corresponding classes. E.g. like:

```
This is a 
<span class="u">car.</span> 
That 
<span class="strong">car</span> 
doesnt't start.
```

And then style them with css like so:

```
span.u{ 
    text-decoration: underline 
}
span.strong{ 
    font-weight: bold
}
```

However using "native" tags is the recommended way.

Answer (score -1):

em -> font-style: italic;
strong -> font-weight: bold;

```html
That is a <span style="font-style: italic">car<span>. That <span style="font-weight: bold">car</span> doesn't start.
```

Comment: How does this answer the question “Can we ignore these HTML elements and replace them by CSS?” In other words, how is “Here’s how to do X?” an answer to “Can we do X?” (or implied: “Should we do X?”)?